# How to multiply using addition

Tags: java

does anyone have an idea how to multiply two integers by using addition in Java?
For example: for i=4 and g=5 the code is supposed to add 4+4+4+4+4 or 5+5+5+5.

It is probably very simple but I have been sitting for hours and still can't figure a way out.
Thanks in advance!

Edit: forgot to mention, it should be done by recursion!

Comment: Have you tried using a loop?

Comment: why are you trying this ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that it should be done by using recursion.

Comment: It's home work for you.

Comment: If it's homework you should solve it yourself, that's the main idea.

Answer (score 2):

```
int i = 4;
int g = 5;

int total = 0;

for (int inc = 0; inc < i; inc++) {
  total += g;
}
```

Comment: This is clearly a homework problem, so should we really just provide working solutions?

Comment: He should have explained what he is doing and why, but I don't see an issue with providing code for "homework" questions. At the very least it will help future browsers.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = -4, b = 5;
    int product = a * b;
    int ans = add(a, b);

    if (ans == product) {
        System.out.println("Answer " + ans + " is correct.");
    } else {
        System.err.println("Answer " + ans + " is NOT correct. Correct is: " + product);
    }
}

/*
 * Sum of g "copies" of i.
 * E.g. add(3, 5) = 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3
 */
public static int add(int i, int g) {
    // A little optimization. 0 * any number = 0
    if (i == 0 || g == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (g < 0) {
        return add(-i, -g);
    }

    // Since we use recursion we need a base case.
    if (g == 1) {
        return i;
    }

    // Define our problem in terms of the same problem, but of smaller size. 
    return i + add(i, g - 1);
}
```

Comment: thanks alot, i will check and try this out!

Answer (score 1):

If you *have* to use recursion, then I'd probably do it this way:

```
public static int multiply(int a, int b) {
    if (a == 0 || b == 0)
        return 0;
    if (a == 1)
        return b;
    if (b == 1)
        return a;
    if (a < 0 && b < 0)
        return multiply(a * -1, b * -1);
    if (a < 0)
        return -1 * multiply(a * -1, b);
    if (b < 0)
        return -1 * multiply(a, b * -1);
    return a + multiply(a, b - 1);
}
```

Comment: 2 * (-1) ... oh ... is there something broken? Ooops!

Comment: @SilviuBurcea Was just editing to handle negatives.

Comment: Yeah, it's working now. However, I don't think you need the if (a < 0) check :)

Comment: thank you, i will try this one out and try to understand each step :)

Comment: could someone give me a tip how to split this in two methods that complement each other?

Answer (score 0):

Could do it with a loop...

5*4 would be

```
int result=0;
int n=5;
int m=4;

for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
{
  result+=n;
}
```

This just loops around `m` times and adds `n` every time to the total.

...or recursively...

```
/**
 * Method 1, the one you call.
 * NOTE: just here to catch 0*n cases
 */
int multiply(int n, int m)
{
   if (n > 0 && m > 0)
     return rec_multiply(n,m);
   else
     return 0;
}

/**
 * Method 2, one that does all the work by 
 * calling itself over and over till the 
 * correct number of additions have been done
 */
int rec_multiply(int n, int m)
{
  return (m==0 ? 0 : multiply(n, m-1))) + n;
}
```

Which calls itself `m` times, adding `n` each time.  Recursion needs to watch for an exit condition or can cause serious endless loop problems though.  The extra method is there to catch 0 entries and 0 * anything is 0.

In recursion you call the method with n=5, m=4.  It calls itself, decreasing the second number by 1 each time.  If it reaches 0 it just returns 5, otherwise it returns another call to itself +5.

Comment: Or you could do it properly with a loop then you wouldn't need to know the result...

Comment: I was being silly, changed my mind

Comment: Your recursive solution is not correct. What is `multiply(0, 1)`?

Comment: I didn't account for user error, intentionally. Spose' I should

Comment: How is that user error? As far as I know, multiplication with 0 is defined in mathematics...although most of these answers don't work with negative value either.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you broke it. :) Now it will only return 0.

Comment: Long day, let's forget recursion, I'm guessing it's a bit much anyway for the question :P

Comment: I'm back...and so is recursion.  How's that?

Comment: will check it out, thanks for the effort :)

Answer (score 0):

Something else which will make your teacher happy is writing a test such as the following:

```
int i = 4;
int g = 5;

int answer = yourMethod(i, g);
int check = i*g;

assert answer == check;
```